# How to set the app icon as the notification icon in the notification drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

As shown in the figure...
I am getting my notification icon(on left to the red colour).
But I need to display the app icon as shown by the black arrow

[image]

```
    public void notify(View view){
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    notification.setTicker("Welcome to ****");
    notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setContentTitle("abcd");
    notification.setContentText("abcd");


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, home.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(uniqueID, notification.build());
}
```

Comment: In your notification builder use .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

Comment: I have posted my code

Comment: @Sathish is incorrect. ic_launcher is not in drawable. Use `setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try this code at your notification builder :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (android.app.NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Set Large icon does the trick.Comment below if you have any further info

Comment: Good, Add this line : .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))

Comment: What if, app is not inforeground

Comment: It shows both large icon and small icon, is  there any way to remove small icon

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code but interestingly, this code keeps crashing System UI in Nexus 5X with latest Android O.

At first, I thought there was something wrong with the application that I was working with but then I created a new application and again the same thing.

This looks like a major Android OS issue.

Comment: not working in 2019. help large icon is still gray circle with white transparent small icon

Comment: Works fine. But the icon is towards the end of the notification. Is there a way to place the icon at the start of notification?

Comment: How to set the large icon on the left side of the text in notification? Currently, I'm getting it on the right side of the text

Comment: @Arjun this is the default behavior where the large icon is on the right hand side of the notifications. One can't really change the same but you can try using remote view through which you can create a custom notification layout and populate the same. With this, I think your use case would get catered.

Answer (score 100):

I know its bit late to answer here and also its already been answered, but I came here looking for an easy fix using firebase notifications. Someone like me visiting here can do the solution by recommended and easy way of firebase notification, which is simply adding meta-data in manifest.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

```
<!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
<!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming notification message. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: how do you make this dynamic ?

Comment: this declaration is also used for firebase default notification handling (when app is in killed state) for dynamic you can use custom in app notifications or modify firebase notifications. Have look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: Helped me to change default icon for Push Notification `Display Messages` type.

Answer (score 0):

Set this parameter while building notification

setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher))