# Issue loading resources when app is not running

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've found similar problems regarding small icons on android notifications, but Google won't give me any hints to following issue:

Simply and short, my notifications won't show color and icon when the app is not opened, but it'll work perfectly while the app is visible on the screen.

App is running in background when notification appears:

[image: App is running in background when notification appears]

App is visible on the screen when notification appears:

[image: App is visible on the screen when notification appears]

For me it seems that the service fails to load some resources with its current context. Currently I'm using my own python server calling the firebase REST Api for sending the notifications.

While Title and Text-Body are sent directly via the notification's own payload, the icon and color are chosen by the app.

This is how the notification is built in the service.

```
final Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.notification))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_local_shipping_white_24dp);
```

And this is the snippet for eventually showing the notification:

```
final NotificationManagerCompat mNotificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
final boolean notificationsEnabled = mNotificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled();
if (notificationsEnabled) {
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grey square as notification icon using Firebase notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157134/grey-square-as-notification-icon-using-firebase-notifications)

Comment: if you test push using firebase push notification tool then push not working well because if your app in background mode at that time notification received then this notification will manage by system and system show your app Icon that's why your app not showing proper notification

Comment: @Manza I've tried to add it to the manifest, but it still won't work. Since I also want to decide which icon to use dynamically it's probably another usecase to. I did read very often that it has to be a white icon on transparent, I also can verify this for the material icon I'm using at the moment.

Comment: @Manza your solution is perfect for TheWhiteLlama(You) just add there lines in your Manifeast.xml

Comment: you have to try push using REST and do not pass notification Message then it's works well

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device read Receive and handle messages content

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama what version of firebase are you using?

Comment: @Manza 9.2.0 for core and messaging.

I've tried the other solutions and it did not work. I'm currently already using REST not the console. But since I want to pass a server side depending notification I don't wanna leave out the message text.

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama the solution I linked works from firebase version 9.8.0. Or check my answer below

Comment: @Manza Oh haha, I thought it was the latest version already. I will try to update and test your solutions again.

Comment: @TheWhiteLlama I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to:

**1.** Update to version 9.8.0 and check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157134/grey-square-as-notification-icon-using-firebase-notifications) solution

**2.**
Set icon and color when sending the push notification.

Example JSON:

```
{
     "notification" : {
      "body" : "My amazing body!",
      "title" : "My amazing title",
      "icon" : "ic_logo",
      "sound" : "default",
      "color" : "#D63A49"
    },
    "registration_ids": ["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]
}
```

**ic_logo** is the resource name

**3.** Send `data` notification. This way the `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)` method will be called even if the app is in backgrdound

Example JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "my_custom_key" : "my_custom_value",
        "whatever" : "YES",
        "other_key" : true
     },
    "to": "XXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: Okay I will try this. One question is still in my mind: How to I set the small icon but just having the resource name?

Comment: the resource name is an icon in your drawable folder :)

Comment: so how will I set the icon? :P the setSmallIcon Method only accepts int parameters

Comment: you are already doing it                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_local_shipping_white_24dp);

Comment: Ahhhh now it works. You're just awesome! So firebase will handle choosing the correct icon by itself when the app is running in background then? Thank you so much!