# Firebase Notification Icon is not coming when App is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I generate the Notification from Firebase notification icon is not coming.(App is in background). Icon is coming if App is in foreground.

I came to know that after lot of research.
If App is in background it won't call `OnmessageReceivedmethod();` 
So for that we have to override `OnHandleIntent()` 
method but I am unable to override it .Why because it is final..

Please give me some solution for this??

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/3789481 ?

Comment: Please just check your code, may be you has written something that stop your service.

   **FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app.Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys.**

Answer (score 0):

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]           
 import android.app.ActivityManager;
            import android.app.Notification;
            import android.app.NotificationManager;
            import android.app.PendingIntent;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.content.SharedPreferences;
            import android.os.Build;
            import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
            import android.text.Html;
            import android.util.Log;

            import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
            import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

            import org.json.JSONException;
            import org.json.JSONObject;

            import java.util.List;

            public class FirebaseMessagingReceiveService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
                private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
                private String the_message = "";
                private String the_title = "ALERT_TITLE";
                public static final String TAG = "FCM Demo";

                private Context mContext;

                @Override
                public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
                    if (remoteMessage == null)
                        return;


                    // Check if message contains a data payload.
                    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                            handleDataMessage(json);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }


                private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());

                    try {
                        the_title = json.getString("DgTitle");
                        the_message = json.getString("DgMessage");

                        sendNotification(the_message, the_title);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                private void sendNotification(String msg, String theTitle) {
                    mContext = getApplicationContext();
                    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


                    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> services = activityManager
                            .getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    boolean isActivityFound = false;

                    if (services.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName().toString()
                            .equalsIgnoreCase(getPackageName().toString())) {
                        isActivityFound = true;
                    }
                    Intent openIntent = null;
                    if (isActivityFound) {
                        openIntent = new Intent();
                    } else {
                        openIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        openIntent.putExtra("Title", the_title);
                        openIntent.putExtra("Message", the_message);
                        openIntent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    }
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                            openIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


                    if (msg != null && (!msg.isEmpty())) {
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 250, 100, 250})
                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                        .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.activity_toolbar_color))
                                        .setContentTitle(theTitle)
                                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                                .bigText(Html.fromHtml(msg)))
                                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                        .setContentText(Html.fromHtml(msg));

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon1);
                        } else {
                            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
                        }

                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


                        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        int notificationNumber = prefs.getInt("notificationNumber", 0);

                        // create unique id for each notification
                        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationNumber, mBuilder.build());

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        if (notificationNumber < 5000)
                            notificationNumber++;
                        else
                            notificationNumber = 0;

                        editor.putInt("notificationNumber", notificationNumber);
                        editor.commit();
                        Log.d("notificationNumber", "" + notificationNumber);

                    }
                }
            }


    this help to start FCM service in background when phone start.

        > 
        > Add receiver in Manifest.xml

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <receiver android:name=".OnBootBroadcastReceiver">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        > OnBootBroadcastReceiver.class

        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;

        public class OnBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent i = new Intent("com.examle.FirebaseMessagingReceiveService");
                i.setClass(context, FirebaseMessagingReceiveService.class);
                context.startService(i);
            }
        }

    > Add following dependency in app gradle.

     //Used for firebase services
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcCZK.png
```

Comment: jaspreet Kaur did'nt worked for me.it still shows grey background with 
 square instead of notification

Comment: please check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157134/grey-square-as-notification-icon-using-firebase-notifications

Comment: please note 
notification_icon1 needed to be 144 X 144 PNG 32 bit color
notification_icon needed to be 48 X 48 PNG 32 bit color

Comment: 144×144 is too big size.
For notification_icon1 and notification_icon is 48×48
If I set same size of icons is it will work For sure..

Please confirm me that Your code is working for you in both forground and background.

Comment: yes, the code is working, the issue is with notification_icon1.. check it and let me know

Comment: Not working jaspreet..please share your icons and class files i will try..Thank you so much for your help and support

Comment: please check i have added notification icon

Answer (score 0):

[image: notification icon 1]

please use this icon for notification icon 1

Comment: 1. resize image 144 X 144 PNG
2. then use the following link to create transparent background image
https://www140.lunapic.com/editor/

Comment: I tried with your Image it is not working ..It is not even going to OnmessageReceived() method if App is in background

Comment: have you add BroadcastReceiver given in my 1 answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have difficulty in setting the icon size use android studio's image asset maker in android studio 3.0.1 which also allows to generate notification icon.

Also try to make your icon single color.

Also set the default icon for firebase notification:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification_default" />
```