# Firebase Notification not showing icon

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I want to send notifications using firebase both when the app is in foreground as well as background. I am able to achieve this but the problem is instead of default firebase notification icon(some white square circle) I want my launcher icon to be displayed. I have implemented following code but still it is not showing. I don't know what is the problem here. Here is the code FirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Dream 11 Prediction Guru");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        //notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

FirebaseInstanceIdService code

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String REG_TOKEN = "REG_TOKEN";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String recent_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(REG_TOKEN,recent_token);
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Firebase console to send push notification or implemented server side?

Comment: using firebase console to send messages

Comment: check this solution I have already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45280972/5928383

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in manifest file:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: Can you add an image of your problema in your question, I need to see what is realy happens thanks. @NikeshPatel

Comment: yup just wait for a minute

Comment: I have added the image which I am getting

Comment: I see, what is the version of firebase that you are using? @NikeshPatel

Comment: its firebase messaging : 10.2.0

Comment: And you are creating notification in code or firebase creates notification yourself ? @NikeshPatel

Comment: I am creating notification in firebase console and then sending to all the users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151275/discussion-between-bruno-ferreira-and-nikesh-patel).