# Fully customised icon for Firebase notifications

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

The background/system tray notification icon for apps like Facebook and Twitter is the profile picture of the person who sent the message. How do they achieve this? Is this possible with Firebase notifications?

I realise that one can specify a 'custom' icon for background notifications with `icon: 'myIcon` in the http post request to the google firebase server, but this drawable resource icon cannot be tailored for each individual message sender.

Comment: they show profile pic inside the app. not in the notification bar.

Comment: it can be tailored if you save the logged in user profile image and use that image as notification icon. if you want to see how I have another answer explaining it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45280972/5928383

Comment: Have you figured out how we can do that?