# FCM Push notification with user's avatar

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to create a push notification like whatsApp or Gmail where the user avatar's is present in the notification. Is there a way to do it in react-native, especially using expo?

this is my payload for fcm

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"title\": \"Sender1\" }, \"text\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```

This is an example which I got from Google which I'd like to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer (Source): [How to set the app icon as the notification icon in the notification drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225779/how-to-set-the-app-icon-as-the-notification-icon-in-the-notification-drawer)
by user [@manikanta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3728438/manikanta)

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (android.app.NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Set Large icon does the trick.Comment below if you have any further info

If you're using React Native (react-native-firebase):

```js
const notif = new firebase.notifications.Notification({                                                                                                             
    show_in_foreground: true,                                                                                                                                                   
})
    .android.setSmallIcon('@mipmap/ic_notification') // app icon

// source image might be:
// URL
// android resource e.g. @mipmap/ic_launcher
let source_image = "";
notif.android.setLargeIcon(source_image) // user avatar
```

Source: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/AndroidNotification#setLargeIcon

Comment: Ah! So the notification should be from local notification? is there a way to do that from remote notification? I'm using expo, so there may be some limitation on this.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was just the name of the variable. This works for remote notif too. Just setup react-native-firebase (https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)

Comment: Hey @JasperMartin do you know how can i achieve this in react native onesignal?

Comment: Hey @JasperMartin do you know how can i achieve this in react native onesignal?